# Memory leak issue : ray + docker + fastapi

Tags: docker, fastapi, ray

When I initialize ray with ray.init() in docker container, the memory usage increases over time(the mem useage in docker stats increases) and container dies when memory over limit (only ray.init() can cause this issue)

Also, too many duplicated processes spawns when ray.init. (RAY:IDLE, ray dashboard, something ray-related processes)
I reproduced this issue with official ray image : https://pypi.org/project/ray/#history

P.S : Our use-case is combination of docker container, fastapi scheduler and ray. (i.e : we initialize ray instance once, and do ray.put, ray.get every pre-defined cycle.)

Let me share my test design pattern to reproduce this issue.

```python
ray.init(num_cpus=4,dashboard_host='0.0.0.0',dashboard_port=8888, configure_logging=False)

app = FastAPI()
@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=1, raise_exceptions=True)
@app.get("/test")
def test():
     dd = []
     bb = ray.put(dd)

     fut = []
     for i in range(10):
          fut.append(aa.remote(bb))
     ss = ray.get(fut)

@ray.remote
def aa(ss):
    a = np.random.rand(380,640)
    ss.append(a)
    return ss
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't help solve your issues, but your issue could be related https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1624 There appears to be memory leak issue with FastApi and Docker